# Problem when decoding a list of int to utf8

Tags: encoding, utf-8, ascii, decode, encode

I have these three lists of decimal char codes from ascii table.

```
[27, 91, 50, 74, 27, 91, 109, 27, 91, 72, 77, 105, 99, 114, 111, 115, 111, 102, 116, 32, 87, 105, 110, 100, 111, 119, 115, 32, 91, 86, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 32, 49, 48, 46, 48, 46, 49, 57, 48, 52, 49, 46, 51, 56, 56, 93, 27, 93, 48, 59, 67, 58, 92, 87, 73, 78, 68, 79, 87, 83, 92, 115, 121, 115, 116, 101, 109, 51, 50, 92, 99, 111, 110, 104, 111, 115, 116, 46, 101, 120, 101, 7, 27, 91, 63, 50, 53, 104, 10]
[40, 99, 41, 32, 50, 48, 50, 48, 32, 77, 105, 99, 114, 111, 115, 111, 102, 116, 32, 67, 111, 114, 112, 111, 114, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 46, 32, 65, 108, 108, 32, 114, 105, 103, 104, 116, 115, 32, 114, 101, 115, 101, 114, 118, 101, 100, 46, 10]
[27, 91, 53, 50, 88, 10]
```

When i decode to UTF-8 i have this.

```
[2J[m[HMicrosoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.388]]0;C:\WINDOWS\system32\conhost.exe[?25h
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[52X
```

How can i avoid these special characters? I noticed that the "escape"(27) character is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

These are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). They control the behavior and appearance of  text terminals and terminal emulators: for example, they can clear the screen, move the cursor, or change the color of text.

These codes can get pretty complicated, especially with style formatting, but the ones in the example you give are easily recognized and removed with a regular expression. You don't tag a programming language, but here is how you might do it in JavaScript.

```
var with_ansi_escapes = "\033[2J\033[m\033[HHello"

var without_ansi_escapes = with_ansi_escapes.replace(/\033\[\d*[A-Za-z]/g, "")
```